# Can't print logging info using my own function for logging in golang

Tags: go

I need to log handled blocks in blockchain system and I need to write logs in different files depending on currency. So what I did:

```
func CreateLogger(currency string, category string) *log.Logger{
    f, err := os.OpenFile(GetBlocksLogByCurrency(currency)+category+".log",
        os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY, 0644)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    defer f.Close()

    logger := log.New(f, "", log.LstdFlags)
    return logger
}
```

So, the function returns the logger but the thing is that

```
blockLogger := CreateLogger("btc", "Blocks")
blockLogger.Println("some log")
```

doesn't work. I tried to debug it. Seems like everything's working fine, but there's no logs in file.

Comment: You're closing the file when you return from `CreateLogger`. You need to not do that.

Comment: @Crowman Oh, it was just a stupid omission... thanks a lot!:)